# How to raise only one exception in python without traceback?

Tags: python, exception, traceback

I wrote a method that accepts any number of arguments. If user passes nothing when calling a method, I know I will get `IndexError` when trying to access first element of `args`.

```
try:
    _color = args[0]
except IndexError:
    print('error')
```

But how to raise some other custom error, when IndexError happens, without traceback of all errors ? I only need one custom.

If I use:

```
try:
    _color = args[0]
except IndexError:
    raise AttributeError
```

I get traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/...", line 12, in __init__
    _color = args[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/...", line 132, in <module>
    Brush()
  File "C:/Users/...", line 14, in __init__
    raise AttributeError
AttributeError
```

I just need to tell user my custom error or in this case `AttributeError`, without `IndexError`.

Comment: If I use `raise CustomError from None`, I still get all the traceback

Comment: Try 'raise CustomError() from None'

Comment: Thank you. Can you make it as an answer so I can reward bounty, but with little explanation so when someone searches and finds this problem, they can read explanation ?